# WSO2 generating a SAML SSO error "Not a valid SAML 2.0 Request Message!"

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I work for a College and I am setting up a sso using WSO2 as SP and NetIQ as IdP. All of the required configuration for both services (IdP and SP) have been exchanged and completed successfully. But I am running into an issue where the WSO2 is throwing the following error from the user's agent (browser):

SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On 
Not a valid SAML 2.0 Request Message! 
The message was not recognized by the SAML 2.0 SSO Provider. Please check the logs for more details

The error "Not a valid SAML 2.0 Request Message!" is so general and doesn't provide any further lead to figure what is the root cause.

Any ideas or suggestions what might be causing this error?

[The screenshot from the user's agent (browser)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaqt6.png)

Comment: you might have to check the log files for more details on NetIQ IDP

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error. You can get some idea on this by looking at the IS console. The best way to investigate is to test this with SAML SSO tracer installed on firefox.

[1] https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sso-tracer/

Try to follow the request , response paths and whether the redirects are correct.